# Ubuntu MATE 17.04 - Must run fsck at every boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, fsck

The disk is a EVO850 M.2 SSD on an AMD a10-7850 processor and 32GB RAM. I am NOT using the AMD R7 graphics, but a GFX1050Ti(proprietary driver) and ASUS AC68 (Broadcom) wireless card.

There are five partitions on sda... sda1 (FAT-EFI), sda2 (ext4,Ubuntu 16.04.02), sda3 (ext4,UbuntuMATE 17.04) sda4 (ext4,data) and sda5 (SWAP)

The drive was partitioned with a live drive install of Ubuntu 16.04 BEFORE UbuntuMATE 17.04 was installed on the pre-existing sda3.

Whenever I boot into 17.04 on sda3, I am dropped to the initramfs> prompt and required to run fsck which makes PAGES of repairs. Then, I am able to boot into 17.04 normally. Even if I immediately reboot - The problem occurs again.

So far, the only applications I have used on 17.04 are Firefox, Chrome, system update and Thunderbird. I am still testing it out. (It doesn't appear to be going well)

The drive is fairly new. And, the problem never occurs when using either Windows 7 or ubuntu 16.04.02. (Windows 7 is installed on sdb1 and was installed prior to both linux distros)

Several posts here ask about this issue. But, none of them (that I have found) have followed through to a solution.

Is this a system bug with 17.04? Just MATE? or is there something I can do to stop the corruption which requires constant fsck on rebooting?

Thanks

[Edit: I added the fastboot directive to the GRUB2 configuration and tried a few reboots. They went OK but, took a very long time to restart.
Then, I allowed the system sit all day with applications open (Firefox, Tbird and Chrome. 
Next, I booted with the Live USB and ran fsck from there - 3 times. fsck reported the volumes as clean each time. I have now disabled the fastboot directive. And, the problem returned.]

I suspect Firefox may be doing something when it saves sessions to the drive. The rationale is that when it first started, Firefox was the only application that I had used and left open... I am now searching for a way to stop Firefox from writing session data, move it to another volume, or at least make sure it doesn't save sessions every 15 seconds. I'll keep trying.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I found on Mozilla's support site a config flag that you allows us to set the interval which Firefox will save session restore data to your drive. in "about:config", search for the "browser.sessionstore.interval" key and set the milliseconds to a (much) higher value. The default is evidently 15 seconds?(?) So, I set mine to 360000, which I THINK should be one hour. It has now been open for 24 hours, and reboot was clean. I am not 100% sure that I have found the answer to file corruption. But, IMO, it is a good idea to set this value higher - especially if FF is constantly shredding an SSD.

Comment: I am 90% certain that the recently pushed core updates (May 29~)have resolved this issue. I have no idea which one. But, two machines with identical configurations have suddenly stopped exhibiting these symptoms. Deep thanks to the developers who "make it go"!